# Visio 2019: Change existing or create new custom connector

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2019

I'm new to Visio. I'm currently playing around with connectors. I can change color of a connector - but Visio will simply not allow me to change the line-type from solid to dash or change the begin/end arrows (even though both options are available via the drop-down in the "Format Shape" window)?

I have also tried to create a copy of a connector and edit its Master - but again nothing happens when I change the drop-down menu? I have also tried to search a lot but not found something which works so far.

Comment: [Edit connector lines, arrows, or points - Visio](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-connector-lines-arrows-or-points-5669491f-9fce-4676-81f8-ef4553788416)

Comment: Can you be more exact? I know this page already - but again ...nothing happens when I change the settings via the "Format-shape" window...?

Answer (score 0):

Select connector, right click, select "Style" - "Line"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it - the issue is that is doesn't work... after many days I found a "hack"...

1. Create a "connector"
2. Right click it and select "Set connector type"
3. Select "Composite"...

FIRST now you can change the different options like "line type" to dash etc...This works! But why Visio is so complicated - I don't get :-/